# My blog shows this weird name Xanga Blog and it should and Estudos e Comentários

Tags: seo, blogger

Around one year when I type my blog address instead of showing the descrition, it shows:

```
Biblioteca Bíblica - Xanga home
Traduzir esta página
Não há nenhuma informação disponível para esta página.
```

Saying that there is no description for main page of the blog. I never changed anything and the box configuration of head tag is normal with the description of the blog.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic symptom of Google's crawler being blocked by the `robots.txt` file on your website.

Here's [Google's help page about it](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7489871).

In short, since the page is blocked, Google cannot crawl it. This means that:

1. Google cannot see the title, so it has to make one up based on links it sees from other websites. This explains why your page's title is weird and unexpected.
2. Google cannot see any of the text or meta tags of the page, so it cannot generate any description. This explains the "no information available for this page" message where the description should be.

To fix this, correct the issues with your `robots.txt` file that are causing crawling of your page to be blocked. Google's [robots.txt testing tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598) may be helpful.

---

I found your website on Google and I can see that you are using Blogger. Blogger has a "custom robots.txt" setting that relates to this.